# Laravel RESTful url parameters handling

Tags: php, laravel, rest, restful-architecture

I am designing a RESTful application and I would like to manage url parameters, at the moment I have this function in controller for the GET that list all the resources api/v1/cats:

```
public function index()
{
    $cats = Cats::all();

    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
        $requirement->view_requirement = [
                'href' => 'api/v1/cat/' . $cat->id,
                'method' => 'GET'
        ];
    }

    $response = [
            'msg' => 'List of all Cats',
            'cats' => $cats
    ];
    return response()->json($response, 200);
}
```

and route is :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function() {

Route::resource('cats', 'CatController', [
        'except' => ['edit', 'create']
]);
```

which is the best way to manage url with for example search parameter like: api/v1/cats?name=Filip&color=black

Answer (score 1):

you should not add any thing to the route file to handle request params
just catch them in the controller as `\Input::all()`

then you can search and retrieve the result.

any you can use this to handle search on model level

https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve GET parameters you can do both ways :

- TypeHint the Request class (global namespace) to inject the Request object and get your parameter via `$request->get('filter')`
- Use the `request()`helper function this way `request()->get('filter')` or the shortcut 'request('filter')

Little tips about REST APIs :
I don't know the stage of development of your project, but there are some guidelines / best practises for REST APIs and I highly encourage you to follow them. It will guide and help you making an awesome, robust, maintenable API. Speaking of experiences ;)

Here is an example : http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api

EDIT : You can of course still use `$_GET`

Comment: There is also this way that I like : `$request->filter`

Comment: and `request()->filter` too ^^